# Symbol related problems

Tags: visual-studio

Can someone tell me what exactly happens when I right click a function name and click on 'Go to Definition'? The reason why I am asking this is because I created a new function in my project, and while performing the aforementioned operation I get a message that the symbol was found found. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE looks in the IntelliSense database for the symbol and reports this message if it can't find it.  The usual advice is to delete the hidden .ncb file in the project directory so the IDE is forced to re-scan the code to rebuild the database.  That usually worked in VS6, not so much in later editions.  Finding the line of code where the IntelliSense parser choked on your code isn't easy.

VS2010 will contain a completely redone IntelliSense parser, hopefully much improved.

Comment: Great! I'm using VS 2008 and deleting the .ncb file worked. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That feature should bring you to the definition of the function: that is, it should open the file in which the function is implemented (the actual code), and place the cursor at the function header.

Basically what is happening in your situation is that the IDE cannot find where the function body is located. Did you `#include` the appropriate file?